# Instance Provisioning with remote-exec in Terraform docs not working on MacOS. Error: timeout

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have been using the terraform docs to learn terraform, but [I'm stuck at this step where I need to SSH into an ec2-instance.](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/provision#defining-a-provisioner)

I'm constantly getting a timeout error after the default 5mins

```
aws_instance.example (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.example (remote-exec):   Host: 63.32.57.5
aws_instance.example (remote-exec):   User: ec2-user
aws_instance.example (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.example (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.example (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
aws_instance.example (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
aws_instance.example (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [5m10s elapsed]
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [5m20s elapsed]


Error: timeout - last error: dial tcp 63.32.57.5:22: i/o timeout
```

normal ssh into the server returns a timeout.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/terraform ec2-user@52.215.89.205
```

returns

```
ssh: connect to host 52.215.89.205 port 22: Operation timed out
```

it is obvious the issue is because ssh is not allowed in the security group. In terraform how do you get the default vpc?

I have found in some answers online (e.g [here](https://gist.github.com/toshimaru/89bf5ab2d3c2c359f07bcdfc835154bb#gistcomment-3020115)) that to make this error go away I need to set up a security group that allows ingress on port 22 into the ec2 instance. But up till this point in the documentation, we've not created or setup any security group, VPC or subnet.

[I also tried to research further in the documentation to try to create my own security group. That's where I found out that a security group also depends on creating a VPC resource.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html) And for sure, after creating a VPC you will have to do some extra configurations like creating your own subnet, routing table, elastic IP, etc.

What is the easy way to fix this? Instead of creating a new VPC, can't I use the credentials of the default VPC. If that is possible, then how?

Here's my terraform code up to this point in the doc.

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  version = "~> 2.49"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "example" {
  key_name = "examplekey"
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/terraform.pub")
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  key_name = aws_key_pair.example.key_name
  ami = "ami-0e61341fa75fcaa18"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  # vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0e8bcd72"]
  # subnet_id = "subnet-6f86e027"

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/terraform")
    host = self.public_ip
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo amazon-linux-extras enable nginx1.12",
      "sudo yum -y install nginx",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]
  }
}


resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  vpc = true
  instance = aws_instance.example.id
}
```

How can I make this timeout error go away?

Comment: If you create an EC2 instance (to be created with your TF) manually from the console, then try to telnet to port 22 of the public IP of the EC2 instance, can you get a connection response from the instance? Or how about ssh -i ~/.ssh/terraform $ec2_publiic_ip? Can you ssh into? If you cannot, then no point to try to make the TF script work.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try this out now and update with the outcome.

Comment: Also please double check "chmod 400 ~/.ssh/terraform" part, and the EC2 OS is Amazon Linux to be able to login with "ec2-user" (I believe CentOS also ec2-user). Ah, the ssh command is ssh  -v -i ~/.ssh/terraform ec2-user@${ec2-public-ip-in-AWS-console}.

Comment: To be honest, if the goal is to learn Terraform, I will remove "connection" and "provisioner" parts to keep it simple. I have not used those personally, although it could be useful for testing purpose to make sure the aws_instance script is working. Later once you get familiar with Terraform, it would be much easier to implement them.

Comment: Yes, I'm just following the docs, if I can't get past this step then I won't be able to continue with the doc.

Comment: So, I just tried. I was not able to ssh manually into the instance. I got this error - ssh: connect to host 52.215.89.205 port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: I'm sure this is because, as I said in the question, you can't ssh into an instance whose security group you have not set up to allow ssh.

Comment: Please try "telnet 52.215.89.205 22". If it does not work, then the port is not open, or something blocking in the middle somewhere between AWS EC2 and your PC.

Comment: Please make sure to allow port 22 incoming in the Security Group attached to the EC2 instance. Otherwise no point to spend more time.

Comment: my question is how do I do that with terraform?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way to add a security group and allow access to ec2 instance from the terraform script. This solution will allow ingress(inbound) and egress(outbound) access into the created ec2 instance.

If all runs successfully, you should see this page when you visit the public IP of the created instance in your browser.

[image]

NB: Make sure to use an ami for EC2 instance that supports `amazon-linux-extras` or add it to the installation in the `remote-exec` provisioner

#### Create Security Group

```
resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "terraform-example-instance"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

#### And then add it to the aws_instance resource like so

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  key_name = aws_key_pair.example.key_name
  ami = "ami-0e61341fa75fcaa18"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]
  # subnet_id = "subnet-6f86e027"

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/terraform")
    host = self.public_ip
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo amazon-linux-extras enable nginx1.12",
      "sudo yum -y install nginx",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]
  }
}
```

My full terraform code now looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  version = "~> 2.49"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "example" {
  key_name   = "examplekey"
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/terraform.pub")
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "terraform-example-instance"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.example.key_name
  ami                    = "ami-099a8245f5daa82bf"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]
  # subnet_id = "subnet-6f86e027"

  # user_data = <<-EOF
  #             #!/bin/bash
  #             echo "Hello, World" > index.html
  #             nohup busybox httpd -f -p 8080 &
  #             EOF

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/terraform")
    host        = self.public_ip
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo amazon-linux-extras enable nginx1.12",
      "sudo yum -y install nginx",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  vpc      = true
  instance = aws_instance.example.id
}
```

The security group solution is an  Excerpt From: Yevgeniy Brikman. “Terraform: Up & Running, 2nd Edition”. Apple Books.